# How do I bind an event to an elements pageshow when there are multiple pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to bind to [pagechange](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/) which is failing to work. Given the following basic page, how do I tell when page 2 is displayed?

```html
<div data-role="page" id='page1'>
  <div data-role="content">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <a href="#page2"
       data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"
       >Open Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id='page2'>
  <div data-role="content">
    <h3>Page 2</h3>
    <a href="#page1"
       data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true"
       >Back to page 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```javascript
$("#page2").bind("pageshow", function(toPage, ui) {
  console.log($(this));
  console.log(toPage);
});
```

The change event never fires, though if I use `$(document)` then it fires, but both `$(this)` and `toPage`

I wish to know when page2 is first presented so I can perform functions to retrieve remote data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page events should be bound like this:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page2" ,function(toPage, ui) {
   console.log($(this));
   console.log(toPage);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qvZst/

But if you want to do something when page2 is available for the first time then you need to use page event called pagebeforecreate

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#page2" ,function() {
   console.log($(this));
   console.log(toPage);
});
```

Unfortunately **`pagebeforecreate`** don't have a toPage because it is a page that is about to be loaded. **`pagebeforeshow`** can also be used because it will trigger before page is shown and you can use it to access previous page data.

To find out more about page events and their order take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

There's also another solution, you can also do it during the **`pagebeforehide`** of a page1 but it will trigger after **`pagebeforecreate`** of a page 2. Page event sequence can be found in my article.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm confused, the [API documentation for pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) defines the usage as `jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pageshow", function( event ) { ... } )` and provides an example to match.

Comment: That is the beauty of development, there are so many ways something can be done. In this case, when working with jQuery Mobile delegated event binding is advised over a classic one where event is binded directly to an page/element. Plus official documentation is very bad.

Comment: Using `pagebeforecreate` may not be practical as I wish to display a loading indicator on the page while data loads. The official documentation is driving me insane and I'm finding it to not live up to the jQuery standard of quality, hopefully people like yourself and me will contribute to it once we get more proficient.

Comment: jQuery Mobile developers are currently working on a documentation cleaning + expending. I can tell you that from the first hand. But it will take time to make it great like Sencha touch documentation.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, that's great. If I had enough experience I would offer to help out.